# I dont know what I did but now all my object move around when I move one object

Tags: objects, camera

Alright what I did is a mystery to me as I'm a new comer to the software and all that but everytime I try move one object (nothing is joined or I dont think it is) everything else follows the object I move, so I tried to move the camera and the objects didnt neccessary follow it but they like split up...

Example... I have a plate, cup and solid model form of liquid (meaning I haven't touched liquid yet so I made a solid object glass so its water now) anyway when i move the camera... then the liquid will stay where it is and the cup will move up and the plate will move down and light source will move in another way...

I have no idea what I did to make this happen and I'm too scared of playing with any settings yet as I dont feel like starting over if I done screw up

Any possibilities on how to fix this... I tried clicking everything and then clear parent but problem still there

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE. It's probably something simple, please share your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, just to make sure :)